# Why the sparse array is ill-conditioned?

Tags: bugs, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.1.0 or later**

---

Given that I have a knot vector $\mathbf U$ and a set of parameter values $\mathbf T$:

```
U = {-0.018310544879457935`,-0.012207034419556506`,-0.0061035194597373055`,0,
     0.007947381024392994`,0.015896985836984207`,0.023849496293520733`,0.0318037494975631`,
     0.03975915901762338`,0.0477153411094262`,0.05567199782586085`,0.06362913932177364`,
     0.0715866937531541`,0.0795446476499281`,0.08750300546212922`,0.09546173691312039`,
     0.10342091295646483`,0.11138055246270329`,0.11934063494463609`,0.12730123948852812`,
     0.1352623862878759`,0.14322404782814827`,0.15118620024759044`,0.15914879056899667`,
     0.16711176492165805`,0.17507508604555258`,0.18303859260454125`,0.19100216524527763`,
     0.19896562480557684`,0.20692900422432328`,0.2148920912932465`,0.22285488990607166`,
     0.23081722841868946`,0.23877899625012167`,0.24674016537051507`,0.2547006557562886`,
     0.2626605712319437`,0.2706197514514926`,0.2785782021068993`,0.28653592356892715`,
     0.2944929268582807`,0.3024492246617148`,0.3104048564483061`,0.3183598587228994`,
     0.3263142945909529`,0.3342681903482628`,0.3422215816384908`,0.3501747584647508`,
     0.35812755237990723`,0.36607998995330615`,0.37403190761856553`,0.3819835289304483`,
     0.3886094255757332`,0.39390964457488653`,0.39788430888435367`,0.4018589782161606`,
     0.40583364754796747`,0.40966627849998927`,0.41589246332954444`,0.4245334531537193`,
     0.4357312838584109`,0.4469504009218613`,0.45816957544280623`,0.4693888401185814`,
     0.4806081760209349`,0.4918276023825066`,0.5030471077373718`,0.5142667313315674`,
     0.5254864642566899`,0.5367063130793907`,0.5479262509429471`,0.5591463163437205`,
     0.5703663844157385`,0.5815866951490725`,0.5928073650583843`,0.6040287621336593`,
     0.6152508517822124`,0.6264738170541829`,0.6376976658624192`,0.648921694734309`,
     0.6601461878038705`,0.6713717498203953`,0.682599803804294`,0.693831315188334`,
     0.7050674703279312`,0.7163084579237454`,0.7275527335316063`,0.7387983309924002`,
     0.7500439354151093`,0.7612892062041845`,0.7725334514413666`,0.7837761124526615`,
     0.7950166325928549`,0.8062547781628725`,0.8174905870790532`,0.8287243101553067`,
     0.8399563055094329`,0.8511870185871537`,0.862416743337147`,0.873645882662241`,
     0.884874491754384`,0.8961027592682634`,0.9073304502318396`,0.9185573329506938`,
     0.9297828880613659`,0.9410061871055874`,0.9522046631777067`,0.961696336629296`,
     0.9694824342007392`,0.9755859446606406`,0.9816894551205421`,0.9877929655804435`,
     0.9938964805402627`,1,1.007947381024393`,1.0158969858369842`,1.0238494962935207`};

T = {0.`,0.007945873121881325`,0.01589626995129766`,0.023848814437773633`,
     0.03180340449149092`,0.03975902956342475`,0.047715042997954475`,0.055671950766899375`,
     0.0636289997127287`,0.07158646748569283`,0.07954461406104081`,0.08750286140305062`,
     0.09546154092229622`,0.10342080841401438`,0.11138038953308387`,0.11934045944101165`,
     0.12730105585981277`,0.13526220316475993`,0.1432238998390551`,0.15118604048062978`,
     0.1591486604230865`,0.16711167080327374`,0.175074963538614`,0.18303862379477004`,
     0.1910021904802397`,0.1989656814608232`,0.20692900247566773`,0.21489232873647895`,
     0.22285494266759273`,0.23081739831414336`,0.23877934427433228`,0.24674024616188933`,
     0.25470090567532366`,0.2626608154316528`,0.27061999258885466`,0.2785784463339704`,
     0.28653616739787297`,0.29449315697493816`,0.3024494562020311`,0.31040506080817526`,
     0.318360052334712`,0.326314463025811`,0.33426836841233576`,0.3422217396066416`,
     0.3501746368964951`,0.35812789889111574`,0.36608012135211093`,0.3740319496166919`,
     0.3819836518868938`,0.3899349852877591`,0.3939096395525468`,0.3978843088843537`,
     0.4018589782161606`,0.4058336475479675`,0.4098083168797744`,0.41335687107222596`,
     0.4245122020366331`,0.43573128635229896`,0.4469503631863009`,0.45816955322698405`,
     0.469388809915134`,0.4806081572136262`,0.49182756093404456`,0.5030470889998492`,
     0.5142666732782218`,0.5254864317166315`,0.5367062877752161`,0.5479262197463246`,
     0.5591462453073006`,0.5703664839775365`,0.5815864239623786`,0.5928071775073025`,
     0.6040284937054722`,0.615250615188203`,0.6264734464529619`,0.6376973895213841`,
     0.6489221616129114`,0.660145533068632`,0.6713708687300681`,0.6825988476624855`,
     0.6938296950203283`,0.7050654028821882`,0.7163073130812772`,0.7275526578077709`,
     0.738798229705771`,0.7500441054636585`,0.7612894710758985`,0.7725340420729966`,
     0.7837768411752049`,0.7950174541097833`,0.8062556024935763`,0.817491277885258`,
     0.8287248808583252`,0.839956771722337`,0.8511872639476367`,0.8624170200914877`,
     0.8736459459723168`,0.8848746819229186`,0.8961028473679171`,0.9073307485139547`,
     0.9185577548136468`,0.9297834955244799`,0.9410074138459712`,0.9522276519463112`,
     0.9633789237408378`,0.9694824342007392`,0.9755859446606406`,0.9816894551205421`,
     0.9877929655804435`,0.9938964760403449`,0.9999999999999998`};
```

Then I got a square coefficient matrix `mat` via corresponding computation

```
n = Length@T - 2;
mat = Outer[BSplineBasis[{3, U}, #2, #1] &, Most[T], Range[0, n + 3]];
{a, b} = Dimensions[mat];
mat = Take[mat, a, a] + PadRight[Take[mat, a, a - b], {a, a}];
```

So my confusion comes from the following operations:

```
LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[mat]
(*6.85852*)

LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[SparseArray@mat]
(*3.69096*10^19*)

LinearSolve[mat]

LinearSolve[SparseArray@mat]
```

> LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix SparseArray[Automatic,<<3>>] may contain significant numerical errors.

[image]

---

#### Update

Via `LinearSolve[mat][pts]`, I can achieve a B-spline curve (defined on control points `ctrlpts` and knot vector `U`) which passes through a set of points `pts`.

```
pts = {{-15.4443,-3.0278},{-14.6621,-2.99274},{-13.88,-2.94865},{-13.0977,-2.90178},
       {-12.3152,-2.85623},{-11.5324,-2.81497},{-10.7492,-2.78035},{-9.96558,-2.75406},
       {-9.18168,-2.73769},{-8.39759,-2.73282},{-7.61345,-2.74044},{-6.82956,-2.76195},
       {-6.04618,-2.79831},{-5.26363,-2.85047},{-4.48236,-2.91951},{-3.7028,-3.0062},
       {-2.92548,-3.11148},{-2.15096,-3.23602},{-1.37985,-3.38049},{-0.612823,-3.54548},
       {0.149415,-3.73153},{0.906107,-3.93913},{1.65654,-4.16843},{2.39993,-4.41973},
       {3.13555,-4.69293},{3.86263,-4.98806},{4.58048,-5.30497},{5.28849,-5.64327},
       {5.98603,-6.00252},{6.67259,-6.38229},{7.34777,-6.78186},{8.01107,-7.20066},
       {8.66237,-7.63783},{9.30137,-8.09267},{9.92798,-8.56433},{10.5421,-9.05199},
       {11.1438,-9.55477},{11.7332,-10.0718},{12.3105,-10.6024},{12.8756,-11.1456},
       {13.4291,-11.7007},{13.9709,-12.2671},{14.5016,-12.8439},{15.0213,-13.4304},
       {15.5305,-14.0262},{16.0294,-14.6305},{16.5183,-15.2428},{16.9977,-15.8626},
       {17.468,-16.4894},{17.9292,-17.1227},{18.2309,-17.3724},{18.6154,-17.4469},
       {18.9886,-17.328},{19.259,-17.0447},{19.3605,-16.6664},{19.2875,-16.3245},
       {18.826,-15.3268},{18.3585,-14.325},{17.8872,-13.325},{17.4117,-12.327},
       {16.9314,-11.3313},{16.4459,-10.3381},{15.9543,-9.34784},{15.4559,-8.36098},
       {14.9499,-7.37804},{14.4352,-6.39961},{13.9106,-5.42643},{13.3748,-4.45933},
       {12.8265,-3.49927},{12.2643,-2.54727},{11.6867,-1.60458},{11.0923,-0.672301},
       {10.48,0.24846},{9.84946,1.15685},{9.19549,2.04863},{8.50955,2.9162},{7.78997,3.75618},
       {7.03722,4.56638},{6.24627,5.33962},{5.41514,6.06988},{4.54293,6.75102},
       {3.6291,7.37605},{2.67399,7.93719},{1.6801,8.42711},{0.651008,8.83807},
       {-0.40862,9.16236},{-1.49236,9.3934},{-2.59242,9.52584},{-3.69983,9.55667},
       {-4.80515,9.48539},{-5.89913,9.31365},{-6.97328,9.04539},{-8.02018,8.68584},
       {-9.03385,8.24155},{-10.0094,7.71909},{-10.9431,7.12529},{-11.8323,6.46675},
       {-12.6746,5.74933},{-13.4684,4.97856},{-14.212,4.15943},{-14.9039,3.29619},
       {-15.5423,2.39285},{-16.1252,1.45294},{-16.6504,0.480036},{-17.1188,-0.513947},
       {-17.2787,-1.09374},{-17.2344,-1.69353},{-16.9912,-2.24359},{-16.5773,-2.67996},
       {-16.0409,-2.9519}};

ctrlpts = LinearSolve[mat][pts];
ctrlpts = Join[ctrlpts, ctrlpts[[1 ;; 3]]];

Graphics[{BSplineCurve[ctrlpts, SplineKnots -> U], Blue, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot explain this behavior but I will note that using `SparseArray @ Chop @ mat` eliminates the message and gives the same `MatrixConditionNumber` as `mat`.

Comment: It certainly is badly conditioned: http://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Gv6.png --  I know hardly anything about sparse solvers.

Comment: @MichaelE2 According to my test, the `LinearSolve[mat][pts]` gives the correct results. Please see Update:)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you:) I also notice this and I don't know why.

Comment: @xyz Yes, it seemed to me that `LinearSolve[mat]` works fine, too, (see `lsM` in linked image in previous comment); but I thought it was the `SparseArray` one you were asking about, which is badly conditioned. Mr.Wizard's fix seems to multiply the error in `lsM[b]` by 1000, which is tolerable in many cases.

Comment: A bug report was filed on this.

Comment: @xyz In case the code in the image wasn't clear: The last input computes the relative errors of `lsSA` and `lsM`.  The method `lsM = LinearSolve[mat]` is accurate to machine precision according to the last output line, but the error  for `lsSA = LinearSolve[SparseArray@mat]` is around `10^19`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks a bunch:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what appears to be a slight improvement on Mr. Wizard's workaround.  How much to `Chop[]` should probably depend on both the magnitude (norm) and precision of the matrix.  Something like this:

```
LinearSolve[SparseArray@Chop[mat, Norm[mat] $MachineEpsilon]]
```

With only one test example, and given that this appears to be a bug, it's hard to test the robustness of this approach.  Note that `lsM = LinearSolve[mat]` is accurate to machine precision.

```
lsM = LinearSolve[mat];
b = mat.(x0 = RandomReal[1, 110]);
Norm[lsM@b - #]/Norm[#] &[x0]
(*  2.07362*10^-16  *)
```

Chopping to machine precision produces a well-conditioned matrix/linear-solve-function, whose error is only a small multiple of `lsM`:

```
lsChop = LinearSolve[SparseArray@Chop[mat, Norm[mat] $MachineEpsilon]];
Table[(b = mat.(x0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 110]);
    Norm[lsChop@b - #]/Norm[#] &[x0])/(Norm[lsM@b - #]/Norm[#] &[x0]),
  {5000}] // 
 Histogram[#, {0.2}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "Error ratio (SA@Chop[$MachineEpsilon]/mat)"] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The default tolerance for `Chop[]` has larger error (by a factor on the order of 1000):

```
lsChop2 = LinearSolve[SparseArray@Chop@mat];
Table[(b = mat.(x0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 110]);
    Norm[lsChop2@b - #]/Norm[#] &[x0])/(Norm[lsM@b - #]/Norm[#] &[x0]),
  {5000}] // 
 Histogram[#, {100}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "Error ratio (SA@Chop[default]/mat)"] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and detailed analysis. In fact,  I write a special function to store the **non-zero values** and corresponding **postions**, then translate them to `SparseArray`, rather than `mat = Outer[BSplineBasis[{3, U}, #2, #1] &, Most[T], Range[0, n + 3]];`. In this process, I found the above phenomenon.:)

Comment: In addition, my workaround is very simple, like `mat = Normal[matSparse]`.

Answer (score 5):

Let me present another workaround. By default, `LinearSolve[]` is using a [multifrontal method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/356044.356047) (`Method -> "Multifrontal"`) on the given `SparseArray[]`, and it seems it is having trouble with the internal thresholding, which results in the erroneous error message.

Thus, you might consider using a different method instead. In particular, the structure of the matrix involved suggests the use of `Method -> "Banded"`:

```
sm = SparseArray[mat];
ls = LinearSolve[sm, Method -> "Banded"];
```

which gives a pretty good result in this case:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42];
            b = sm.(x = RandomReal[1, 110]);
            Norm[lsx[b] - x, ∞]/Norm[x, ∞]]
   2.2219*10^-16
```

---

Here is a histogram similar to Michael's for the `"Banded"` strategy, with the slight replacement of using the max-norm instead of the 2-norm:

[image: histogram]

Comment: I felt sure that someone would know or figure out how to adjust the method.

Comment: It is first time for me to know that using the **Method** option of `LinearSolve`. Thanks a lot.